# IE7: Hover an Image will show another image at different place

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a few images one on top of each other in a form of a "menu".

I would like that while I hover one of the images, it will show another image.
I also would like that while hovering each image, it will go up by 5px (currently it does not).

**It must support Internet Explorer 7 or higher.**

I hope what I have requested is possible and really appreciate any help you can provide.

My code so far:

```css
.hw { font-size: 50px; padding: 50px; }

.first {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.second {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
}

.third {
  position: absolute;
  right: 360px;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  bottom:60px;
  left: 100px;
}

.first:hover, .second:hover, third:hover {
  bottom: 5px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.logo:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
  
  <p class="hw">Hello World!</p>
  
  
  <img class="hidden" src="http://i.imgur.com/MY5bRT1.jpg" style="position: relative; bottom: 80px; right: 500px;"/>
  
  <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img class="first" src="http://i.imgur.com/cr2cqPA.png"/>
    <img class="second" src="http://i.imgur.com/MY5bRT1.jpg"/>
    <img class="third" src="http://i.imgur.com/cr2cqPA.png"/>
    <img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/MY5bRT1.jpg"/>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: solution:

```css
.hw {
 font-size: 50px;
 padding: 50px;
}

.menu {
 margin-right:300px;
}

.first {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.second {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
}

.third {
  position: absolute;
  right: 360px;
}

.forth {
  position: absolute;
  right: 540px;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  bottom:60px;
  left: 100px;
}

.first:hover, .second:hover, .third:hover, .forth:hover {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.img-con {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.img-con > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.img-con > img.logo {
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-con:hover > img.logo {
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.img-con:hover > img.hidden {
  top: -100px;
  right: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>bla bla</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body dir="rtl"><div class="center">
 <p class="hw">Hello World!</p>
  
 <div class="menu" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
   <div class="img-con">
    <img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/cr2cqPA.png"/>
    <img class="hidden" src="http://i.imgur.com/MY5bRT1.jpg"/>
   </div>
   
   <img class="first" src="http://i.imgur.com/cr2cqPA.png"/>
   <img class="second" src="http://i.imgur.com/MY5bRT1.jpg"/>
   <img class="third" src="http://i.imgur.com/cr2cqPA.png"/>
   <img class="forth" src="http://i.imgur.com/MY5bRT1.jpg"/>
 </div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE7? Really? Out of curiosity, why the IE7 requirement? Is it for a business, or some region that still has a high use of this browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for you. You need insert every two image to container and set him with `Relative` position. Your images sets by `Absolute` position and you can play with there `z-index` on `:hover` to get the resolute.

**Here we go:**

```css
.img-con {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.img-con > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.img-con > img.first {
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-con:hover > img.first {
  z-index: -1;
}

.img-con:hover > img.second {
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-con">
    <img class="first" src="http://i.imgur.com/cr2cqPA.png"/>
    <img class="second" src="http://i.imgur.com/MY5bRT1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Just on a quick glance: IE7 doesn't support `first-child` or `last-child` so I don't see how this would work.

Comment: After a little bit of changes, I could manage to get it work!
It works perfectly! Thank you ever so much. I really do appreciate it.Now, the only things is... why can't I make the three images to go upwards while hover (currently only the middle one does).

Will publish my code as soon as it will be all fixed.

Comment: You cant uses 3 images because you have only 1 event (hover). You can add a new event like focus or active.

Comment: I meant that I would like each image to go up by 3px while hovering the specific image. Currently I can only make them go down.

Comment: I would like to use `.first:hover, .second:hover, .third:hover, .forth:hover { margin-bottom: 3px; }`, so by hovering each image, it will go up. Yet, currently, it doesn't move up and the only setting I can do is to use `margin-top`

Comment: Appreciate all of your help! thank you ever ao much.